# How to download an image properly from the web using 'urllib.request' in Python 3.7?

Tags: python, download, pycharm, urllib, python-3.7

I tried to download an image from the web using Python 3.7. But I got some error in my code and I cannot understand what is wrong in my code and how to recover it.
I use PyCharm 3.4 and MacOS X:

**My Code:**

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://www.digimouth.com/news/media/2011/09/google-logo.jpg", "local-filename.jpg")
```

**Error**

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 65] No route to host>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct. However, the *link itself* is dead; hence the error.

Simply use `urllib.request.urlretrieve(url=link, filename=output)`, your approach is correct. If the `url` is an image, you download an image. If the `url` is an HTML file, you download a HTML file.

Your error `urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 65] No route to host>` is because your link is **broken**. The `urlretrieve` only works for non-broken links. Additionally, `urlretrieve` is considered to belong in the legacy interface.

Unfortunately, there is nothing you can do to fix the URL "http://www.digimouth.com/news/media/2011/09/google-logo.jpg" and it also appears to be suspicious now.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided works for a different picture, for example:

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi7nsiIqqXgAhUnuqQKHY6uDa4QjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FGiraffe&psig=AOvVaw1g8lkjuT8Ly2FxVhGp1vp6&ust=1549481373274429", "giraffe.jpg")
```

The problem is with your link, as `http://www.digimouth.com/news/media/2011/09/google-logo.jpg` seems to be dead. Even `wget http://www.digimouth.com/news/media/2011/09/google-logo.jpg` does not work in terminal and Chrome cannot open that link properly. So I suggest to choose a different image.

For SSL error, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28052583/8565438

Comment: ,,,I copy and paste your link to my code but this time following error occured: ```urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1045)>```

Comment: No still the code cannot download images from the given website: I added the followings:
```import ssl```
```context = ssl._create_unverified_context()```